# Rails 3.2.7 and Spree 1.1.2. When I try to access CART, there is debug info show that "undefined method `password_salt=' .."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, password-encryption

I installed rails on Windows7 using RailsInstaller (v2.1.0). I found the original rails was v3.2.1. After that, I "gem install spree". It seems the installation upgrades rails to v3.2.7. I mentioned that because before yesterday it was just 3.2.6. Every thing goes well under rails 3.2.6, but if I "spree install" a rails 3.2.7 app, I failed to access the default store's Cart. And get the error like this:

```
NoMethodError in Spree::OrdersController#edit

undefined method `password_salt=' for #<Spree::User:0x68438d0>
```

As I checking the database, yes, there is no "password_salt" but only "salt" in spree_users table.

Is there anyone else encountered this problem?  I had taken almost half day on this problem. Did I miss something in the Spree path?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Have you run your DB migrations?

Comment: Hi, @Ray. First time, I didn't do anything to migration, but only the default process when "spree install". It didn't work. So I did it "rake db:drop / rake db:migrate" by myself again. Still didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I had the exact same issue before, see if specifying spree gem version (assuming is 1.1.2) in the Gemfile and then running bundle update works

```
#Gemfile
gem 'spree', '1.1.2'
```

and later run

```
bundle update
```

See if it works!

Comment: OK... This is my fault. It seems spree's authorization is different from other components. According to the samples here [link](https://github.com/spree/spree#running-tests), if I want to "Use Dedicated Spree Devise Authentication", I have to do more things. :) Now, my sample app works well. Thank you very much.